# Unlink file permission denied

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-4

I have trouble unlink a directory. Before unlink, I using `Excel::load` function to load my file then use `unlink()` at the end. The problem is I always get the error `permission denied`. I'm not sure which part goes wrong.

Current Code

```
$import_data = Excel::load($this->upload_dir . '/' .Input::get('filename'), function($reader){
                          })->get();

unlink($this->upload_dir . '/' . Input::get('filename')); <---Error
```

Previous code

```
$import_data = Excel::load($this->upload_dir . '/' . Input::get('filename'))
                          ->limit(false, 1)
                           ->get();
unlink($this->upload_dir . '/' . Input::get('filename'));
```

My previous code work without this issue. However, using the previous code I couldn't get the data from the file. Therefore, I changed to my current code that gets data successfully but hit the unlink error.

Comment: I think the file is still open when you are trying to unlink it. Try closing the file before unlinking it.

Comment: I did try the `fclose` but doesn't work. Cause I didn't use the `fopen` to read my file.

Comment: Are you sure the $reader is not keeping the file open ?

Comment: This I'm not sure, maybe I can try to fclose that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you completely sure the old code is still working?

"Permission denied" might simply mean your current server user (i.e. Apache / www-data) has no permissions to delete the file.

You should check the file's permissions, and that your server has actually permissions to manipulate the file.